# PHP installation issue on a Windows Server hosted in the Azure cloud

Tags: windows, mysql, php, azure

I am trying to setup PHP and MySQL on a Windows Server that is currently in Azure cloud using the information from this blog post 
[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/africaapps/archive/2013/11/05/creating-a-wimp-stack-windows-server-iis-mysql-php-on-windows-azure.aspx]

Now I am testing the PHP installation using the methods specified in that tutorial. 
Here are the steps:

1.Open C:\inetpub\wwwroot and add an index.php.

2.Save the file then go to `xxxx.cloudapp.net/index.php`

But when I do that I will get:

> 404 file or directory not found error

I can see the default page at `xxx.cloudapp.net` in the browser, but can’t see the PHP file in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have mapped Php-cgi.exe in IIS properly.

Check the following resource for more information:

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/246/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis7/

Thanks,